# Can't create site in trial Enterprise Edition?

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, nonprofit-starter-pack, trial

A few days into our trial of non-profit (NPSP) EE, I'm trying to test public-facing web pages that don't require login, crucial for our applications. It actually lets me reserve my (sub-) domain, but when I then try to go ahead and create a "site", I get:

```
Site creation failed: You have exceeded the number of licenses for your organization. You must first acquire a new license to create a new site.
```

Plenty of our 10 free licenses left, of course. I would just assume it's a poorly worded error and I can't do this for the trial edition, were it not for the fact it seemed to happily reserve my (sub-) domain name. I also can't quite see the reason for making this a restriction, but perhaps at the trial stage no human has looked at us and after we sign up (still for free!) maybe a human confirms that we're a real charity and they feel more secure then.

Anyway, question is: is this an undocumented (here: https://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf) limitation of trial editions, or did I do something wrong?  If it's a trial limitation, I guess we have to just go ahead and get the free non-profit version to really "try" the software.

Answer (score 2):

Trial orgs do not have Site.com licences, you have to contact your Account Manager at Salesforce, maybe they can get you one.